# Vim-LaTeX - How to auto close brackets and how to compile using vim-commands

Tags: vim, compilation, latex, brackets

I would like to know how to close brackets like (), {} and [] by only typing (, { or [ once when using Vim-LaTeX. I would also like to know how to do it in a way so that my cursor ends inside a bracket after vim closes the bracket. As of now I try to write the following in my .vimrc-file, but it does not work in .tex-files:

```
inoremap { {}<Left>
inoremap {{ {
inoremap {} {}<Left>

inoremap ( ()<Left>
inoremap (( (
inoremap () ()<Left>

inoremap [ []<Left>
inoremap [[ [
inoremap [] []<Left>
```

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this?
Another question: Right now I compile LaTeX-files in Vim-LaTeX by pressing \ll but is there a way to do it using a vim-command? Like

```
:CompileSomething
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vim-latex uses a specific *pattern* to defines mappings: it relies on the plugin named IMAP (or IMAPS?). If you want to define mappings while IMAP is around, you'd better use its functions. Otherwise you'll likely observe odd behaviours.

Regarding bracketing systems and compatibility with IMAP, my [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/) detects if IMAP is installed before defining its mappings in order to define compatible mappings. Opening brackets characters (let say `(`) will trigger the insertion of the related pair + a placeholder (like with vim-latex) + the cursor moved in the right place (-> `(<cursor>)<+placeholder+>`). And hitting the closing bracket key will jump to the placeholder (and thus close the brackets pair) if the cursor is just before the closing bracket characters. However I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for.
Though, context can be analysed to tune the exact behaviour. See the markdown bracket mappings for instance.

EDIT: Regarding the command, you can always roll up your own with (untested)

```
command -nargs=0 CompileLaTeX :exe "normal \\ll"
```

Comment: Thanks! I have now managed to install the plugin "Ih-brackets". But how do you use it like you describe?

Comment: I have updated the [documentation about the default mappings](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/doc/default_brackets.md). Does it answer your question? BTW, you'll have to make sure your plugins manaer loads vim-latex before lh-brackets for it to correctly go in compatible mode.

Comment: the plugin works great. however, for latex, i would like "(" to be mapped into \left(cursor  right)<++>, and likewise with the visual mode variation . Is it possible to change the map that is build into the plugin ?

Comment: Yes, you can override it into a latex ftplugin that is called after mine (`:h rtp`). The new mapping would be `:Bracket \\\\<\left>( ) -trigger=(`. However, I guess this mapping would make sense only within a formula context => we should define an `-open()` function that checks the context in order to insert either `(` or `\<left>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Question.

   you can modify your `.vimrc` file with this statement:

`:inoremap ( ()<Esc>i`

Here is a clearer explanation:
[Autobrackets](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key)

EDIT:
Did you done this things in your `.vimrc` file?
[Correct Settings for VIM Latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html)

Comment: It does not seem to work in LaTeX-files. It works in all other files. I do not know why. As I said, the solution above also works for non-LaTeX-files, but not for LaTeX-files. I do not not know what Vim-LaTeX overwrites, if it does overwrite anything.

Comment: oh sorry, i just overfly your question quickly ;/

Comment: That's okay. I just hope someone can help me. :-/

Comment: Yep, I have made those changes as well as some other changes.